# How pass string value as firestore query?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want only those documents from firestore which has a particular tag.

Here is my code

```
 class ByCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  String tag;
  ByCategory(this.tag);
  @override
  _ByCategoryState createState() => _ByCategoryState();
}

class _ByCategoryState extends State<ByCategory> {

  final CollectionReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection("users").where('tags', arrayContains: widget.tag);
  }
```

*widget.tag* is not same as 'tag'.

Is there any way how both tag are same?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The question is a little unclear to me (sorry), are you wanting to see what the value of widget.tag is when the collection reference is created?

Comment: Yes.    @OneLunchMan

Comment: Did you try putting a debugger on the line that creates the reference `final CollectionReference collectionReference` to see what the value of `widget.tag` is? Alternatively to test queries in order to validate expectations, you can create a button/method and execute the query with dummy data.

Comment: Doesn't work @OneLunchMan

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.